# How to get userdetail from Active directory MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ldap

I'm developing a web application using ASP.NET MVC4 (C#) where i managed to create log in system using LDAP (Active Directory), but I've no idea how to retrieve log in information such as FullName, Email, etc after log in.

for the log in information will be shown on header for every page.

here's my code for log in :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            if (this.Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
            {
                return this.Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "home");
        }
        this.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return this.View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer, with this code inside my controller :

```
 var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
 var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, id);
 var EmployeeID= principal.SamAccountName;
 var firstName = principal.GivenName;
 var lastname = principal.Surname;
```

I managed to get the detail log in information :)